Gradient of function with error term
Given a function
$$f \in C^\infty:R^n\to R  \text{ such that } f(x) = \frac{||x||^2}{2} + o(||x||^2) \text{ and }(n \geq 2)$$
The lecture I'm taking states that $\nabla f(0) = 0$ and I just don't get why.
I know that with $g(x) = \frac{||x||^2}{2}$ we have $\nabla g(0) = 0$ but how do I proceed with this error term $o(||x||^2)$.
I know that per def:
Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $g: U\to \mathbb{R}$, $x_{0} \in U$. Then $\sigma(g)$ contains the functions $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$, which satisfy:
$$\lim_{ x \to x_{0}, x\neq x_{0} } \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=0$$
Why is $\nabla f(0) = 0$?
EDIT: Because the comments are pain. I understand the approach provided in the comments with the expansion. I'm trying to understand the limes solution borught up in the answers. This is what I couold come up based on the answer why does this then imply $\nabla f(0) = 0$
$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-\nabla f \cdot(x)}{||x||^2} = \frac{o(||x||^2) -\nabla f \cdot(x)}{||x||^2} = \frac{o(||x||^2)}{||x||^2} - \frac{\nabla f \cdot(x)}{||x||^2} = -\frac{\nabla f \cdot(x)}{||x||^2}$

Per def $f(x)=f(0)+\nabla f(0).x+o(x)$, hence with the assumption on $f$, $f(0)=0$ and $\nabla f(0).x+o(x)=o(x)$ which entails $\nabla f(0)=0$.

Thank you absolutely forgot about the expansion properties here.

Here’s a more explicit way to see this.
Assume without loss of generality that $f(0) = 0$ (if not, take $f - f(0)$). To show the gradient is $0$, it suffices and is necessary to show that $\lim_{||h|| \rightarrow 0} \frac{|f(h)|}{||h||} = 0$. But note, this equals $\lim_{||h|| \rightarrow 0} \frac{|f(h)|}{||h||^2} \frac{||h||^2}{||h||} = (\frac{1}{2} + 0) \cdot 0 = 0$.
Note also that the above fails if $f = ||x||$, since then the first limit in the above decomposition would evaluate to $\infty$. So, your assumption on the local growth of $f$ is needed for the finiteness of the first term’s limit, which allows the above limit of product to equal a (well-defined) product of limits.

I understand the approach here but don't I have to show this? Assume $f(0) = 0$ we know $f$ is differentiable so we check via def if $\nabla f(0)$ needs to be $0$ so $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-A\cdot(x-x_0)}{||x-x_0||} = 0$ has to hold and that A is $\nabla f$? Here especially:  $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-\nabla f \cdot(x)}{||x||} = 0$ How does this imply $\nabla f (0)= 0$

I suppose you’re pointing out the absolute value in my numerator: but that is equivalent to what your definition is (in case of functions into $R$), and in fact more general (see the definition of gradient of multi variable functions in Spivak for ex., although I think Wikipedia would also have this).

So you want to show that $0$ satisfies the derivative property at $x = 0$ (implying $0$ is the derivative $\nabla f(0)$). Thus, wherever you see $A$ (in the equation of your comment), we plug in $0$, and we show that the limit is $0$. If it works, by uniqueness of the derivative we have our claim. In particular, whereas with real-valued functions we can ‘compute’ our gradient by these limiting methods, in the most general case of functions $R^n \rightarrow R^m$, it is often easier to guess and check (why?). The latter strategy proves more useful here.

Oh I completly forgot about the uniqueness part. Thank you so much
